# Complies on one computer, but not another

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bluej

I'm trying to compile a code in bluej that draws a simple rectangle:

```
import images.APImage;

public class ConstructorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        APImage blank = new APImage(500, 600);

        blank.draw();
    }
}
```

I get the error message "package images does not exist". I wrote the same code earlier on another computer and it compiled and ran, so what is going wrong?

Comment: I guess the `images.APImage` comes from a jar file or classes directory that is on the classpath on one computer and not on the other

Comment: Agree with @hotzst. Looks like you need to get the package from here: http://home.wlu.edu/~lambertk/hsjava/edition4/whatsnew/image.html